# django rest framework problems wiht reverse url

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm having problems with Django Rest Framework reverse function (from rest_framework.reverse import reverse) and django_reverse.

When I try to return the url of a single object, I'm getting all the url pattern, instead of the ID I get the text representation of the model.

For example I have a model called Driver, when I try to get the url of a Driver instance with pk=1, the response is

http : //base_url/driver/**driver%20object**/.

This can be resolve by overriding Driver **unicode** function to return str(self.pk), but I don't like this approach.

Also previous versions of django/drf did not present this issue.

First of all my virtual-env is:

- Django==1.8.4
- django-braces==1.8.0
- django-extensions==1.5.5
- django-filter==0.10.0
- django-oauth-toolkit==0.8.1
- djangorestframework==3.3.2
- psycopg2==2.6
  etc

**Models**

```
    class Dominio(AuditableModel):
        dominio = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
        pais = models.ForeignKey(Pais, null=False, blank=False)

        @property
        def owners(self):
            if self.conductores.count() > 0:
                return self.conductores.filter(is_owner=True).all()[0]
            else:
                return None


    class Conductor(AuditableModel):
        usuario = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False, blank=False, related_name='dominios')
        dominio = models.ForeignKey(Dominio, null=False, blank=False, related_name='conductores')
        is_owner = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False)
        #
        # def __unicode__(self):
        #     return str(self.pk)

        class Meta:
            verbose_name_plural = "conductores"
```

**Serializers**

```
    class ConductorSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Conductor
            fields = ('id', 'url', 'usuario', 'dominio', 'is_owner')


    class DominioSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
        owners = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(read_only=True, view_name='conductor-detail')
        class Meta:
            model = Dominio
            fields = ('id', 'url', 'dominio', 'pais', 'owners')
```

**result**
"owners": "http : //localhost:8000/ventana/api/v1/conductores/Conductor%20object/"

[Django rest framework api response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2sg1.png)

but, if I change the @property owners method to return a list of drivers (conductores), then the urls are correct

**Models**

```
    class Dominio(AuditableModel):
        dominio = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
        pais = models.ForeignKey(Pais, null=False, blank=False)

        @property
        def owners(self):
            if self.conductores.count() > 0:
                return self.conductores.filter(is_owner=True).all()
            else:
                return []
```

**Serializers**

```
    class DominioSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
        owners = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True, view_name='conductor-detail')
        class Meta:
            model = Dominio
            fields = ('id', 'url', 'dominio', 'pais', 'owners')
```

**Result**
"owners": [             "http : //localhost:8000/ventana/api/v1/conductores/1/"]

[Django rest framework api response 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZq9C.png)

Comment: Did you try to use the `lookup_field` field on `HyperlinkedRelatedField`? Take a look [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#hyperlinkedrelatedfield)